# Salesforce Dx - stuck in configuration

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm following this trailhead tutorial on Salesforce Dx:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx

When I use this command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login
```

i've a response error:
'EACCES': listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:1717

any ideas?
which is the best practice to follow that tutorial?
thanks in advance

Comment: That looks like a network error on your local machine/network. Do you have a firewall in place?

Comment: i've also disabled my firewall. How can i restart a clean tutorial?

Comment: Just try the login command again.

Comment: Check if there is any other application using port 1717. Also kill node.js process and try again.

Comment: i tried also netstat...but nothing..how can i kill it?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem today.

And what I did to get over it was to change that default port 1717 to something else.

The steps are as below.

1. Open a `Command Prompt` window.
2. Go to a folder in your local machine using `cd` command. For example, in my case: `cd Samples\Salesforce\my_sfdx_project`
3. Create a Salesforce DX project using `sfdx force:project:create` command. In my case: `sfdx force:project:create -n force-proj01`
4. In the newly created folder `force-proj01`, open `sfdx-project.json` file and add following line: `"oauthLocalPort": "7717",`. The file will eventually contain:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "oauthLocalPort": "7717",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

5. Log in using the command `sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub`. Now the browser window can open up. Fill in your user name and password to log in.
6. The browser now will redirect to such a link as `http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=...`, which is not existing.
7. Change the port in the link above from `1717` to `7717` and press Enter.
8. Now you can log in to Dev Hub successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, saved me a bunch of time.