# Error trying to authorize dev org for trailheads and vscode

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Not sure what's going on here but I'm following the following trailhead and trying to authorize my dev org for use with vs code:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component

When I run the command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vsCodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

The browser opens to the login page then after I login i get the error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> localhost sent an invalid response.

It redirects to https://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code={{code}}

I read many posts where the issue seems to be a network or firewall issue or another process already listening on that port. I verify that there's nothing listening on port `1717` before i run the sfdx command and when I run the command i'm not getting a `refused` error or anything in fact after I run the command in a separate window i run:

```
netstat -ano | findstr 1717
```

and can verify that the process listening on that port is `sfdx`. For good measure i tried to use a different port as others suggested by specifying `oauthLocalPort` in the sfdx-project.json file. When I do this the redirect still goes to port `1717` at which point I do get a connection refused, which I would expect as no one is listening there now, I change the port on the URL to the one i specified and i'm back to square 1 which is the error:

> localhost sent an invalid response.

If anyone can shed anymore light on this it would be appreciated.

Comment: r u vscode commands are running any corporate firewall network?

Comment: @sdandamud1 No i'm not

Comment: then you have to go through link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226114/salesforce-dx-stuck-in-configuration

Comment: @sdandamud1 I tried that already along with creating a new connected app and specifying a different port, no luck on both accounts

Comment: i think it's look like issue with your network, your machine network running under firewall

Comment: I thought so as well so i disconnected from the corporate network and connected via my phone's hotspot, same error. I don't think it's connection related though, i can connect but the error i'm getting is `localhost sent an invalid response.`

Comment: even though u change the network some how still using same port, can you kill the process and try with multiple times  see this topic in the Salesforce DX Dev Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_troubleshoot_cancel_auth.htm

Comment: @sdandamud1 I've tried. Before I run my sfdx command I make sure another process isn't listening on that port, i then run the sfdx command, the error happens and when i check the port again i can verify that sfdx is listening on it. When I change the port in the sfdx-project.json file it initially redirects to `1717` then when i change the url port to the one i specified i get the same error again

Comment: instead of using the login.salesforce.com, try using the named domain instead.

Comment: Hi @ortizjoe Also tried that :) no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your chrome HSTS settings force the use of https for localhost.  See if deleting the HSTS for localhost per https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/ works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer points out, you need to clear your HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) settings relating to Salesforce and Localhost.

1. Open Chrome; navigate to chrome://net-internals/#hsts
2. Into the Delete Domain Security Policies input field type in `login.salesforce.com`
3. Click Delete
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 with `test.salesforce.com` and `localhost`

It's worth noting that I'm unaware of custom configurations you've completed on your system relating to development using the localhost hostname. If you have set up custom self-signed SSL certificates for example for other development reasons, doing this may clear those.

I've pulled some of my research on this issue from [this stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046774/working-way-to-clear-hsts-flag-in-firefox-and-chrome-set-with-preload).